# How to use the open source of any plugins or npms in ionic 2

Tags: plugins, npm, ionic2, addition

I want to know how can I use the functions or files of any plugins or npms that shared in other sites with my project work ?

**for example**, some ionic tutorials ends with some links that contains the open source of their work such as this [ https://github.com/doo/scanbot-sdk-example-ionic2 ] or [ https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example ]

So, My steps (but I don't know if its correct or not because I had errors):

- I download the files and execute this cmd command "**npm install**" to generate "node_modules" folder.
- then, I write "**ionic platform add android**" to add the platform and plugins
- finally, I copied the the plugins to my project folder plugins and copied the functions but I don't know why I got errors in my project for this step!?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: its dependent on added codes to my project. usually the errors about some thing like "the imported *** not defined" or something like this